# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected input[1, 3, 6, 7] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Tags: numpy, pytorch

There is 6x7 numpy array:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

Model is training normally, when it is passed to this network:

```
class Net(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    def __init__(self, observation_space: gym.spaces.Box, features_dim: int = 256):
        super(Net, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        # We assume CxHxW images (channels first)
        # Re-ordering will be done by pre-preprocessing or wrapper
        # n_input_channels = observation_space.shape[0]
        n_input_channels = 1
        print("Input channels:", n_input_channels)
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
        )

        # Compute shape by doing one forward pass
        with th.no_grad():
            n_flatten = self.cnn(
                th.as_tensor(observation_space.sample()[None]).float()
            ).shape[1]

        self.linear = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_flatten, features_dim), nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, observations: th.Tensor) -> th.Tensor:
        return self.linear(self.cnn(observations))
```

6x7 numpy array is modified to 3x6x7 numpy array:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]]
```

After modifying the array, it is giving this error:

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected
> input[1, 3, 6, 7] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

In order to solve this problem, I have tried to change the number of channels:

```
n_input_channels = 3
```

However, now it is showing this error:

> RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected
> input[1, 1, 6, 7] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

How can I make network accept 3x6x7 array?

**Update:**
I provide more code to make my case clear:

6x7 input array case:

```
...
board = np.array(self.obs['board']).reshape(1, self.rows, self.columns)
# board = board_3layers(self.obs.mark, board)
print(type(board))
print(board)
return board
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

Number of channels is 3:

```
n_input_channels = 1
```

It is working.

I am trying to modify array to 3x6x7:

```
board = np.array(self.obs['board']).reshape(1, self.rows, self.columns)
board = board_3layers(self.obs.mark, board)
print(type(board))
print(board)
return board
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]]
```

Number of channels is 3:

```
    n_input_channels = 3
```

I do not understand why it is showing this error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 6, 7] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model can work with *either* 1 channel input, or 3 channels input, but not both.

If you set `n_input_channels=1`, you can work with `1x6x7` input arrays.
If you set `n_input_channels=3`, you can work with `3x6x7` input arrays.

You must pick one of the options - you cannot have them both simultanously.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I want to work with 3x6x7 input array. As I wrote in question, I am getting error: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 6, 7] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead. I want to the network accept 3x6x7 input array

Comment: @JoeRakhimov you set `n_input_channels=3` but the input array you used was `6x7` and **not** 3x6x7 - this is what the error message you got said.

Comment: I think I am using 3x6x7 input array. I have added code how I am doing it. Please have a look in Update part

Comment: thank you for your answer again, problem was in another place. I have this: shape=(1, self.rows, self.columns). Changed to this shape=(3, self.rows, self.columns). Now it is working