# Incorrect input of CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm training a neural network by inputting image batches. Each patch contains 32 images of size 224x224x3. For training I use this code:

```
model.train()
loss_over_time = []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):  
    
    running_loss = 0.0

    for batch_i, data in enumerate(trainLoader):
        
        images = data['image']
        n_input_channels = 1
        key_pts = data['keypoints']

        key_pts = key_pts.view(key_pts.size(0), -1)

        key_pts = key_pts.type(torch.FloatTensor)
        images = images.type(torch.FloatTensor)

        output_pts = model(images)

        loss = criterion(output_pts, key_pts)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if batch_i % 32 == 31:    # print every 32 batches
            print('Epoch: {}, Batch: {}, Avg. Loss: {}'.format(epoch + 1, batch_i+1, running_loss/32.0))
            loss_over_time.append(running_loss/32.0)
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
return loss_over_time
```

But I'm faced with the error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 1, 3, 3], expected input[32, 224, 224, 3] to have 1 channels, but got 224 channels instead
```

I had searched in StackOverflow and other sites. Seems like I define the number of input channels like ([RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected input[1, 3, 6, 7] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057069/runtimeerror-given-groups-1-weight-of-size-32-1-3-3-expected-input1-3)):

```
n_input_channels = 1
```

But I can't find a way how to do it.

Comment: The error is either in your input dimensions, something wrong with your dataloader, or with your model layers (looks like the first one). Not enough info or reproducibility to give you anything more.

Comment: Pytorch uses channels first data format. Transpose your dimensions to 3 x 224 x 224.

Comment: @xdurch0 I tried to use torch.transpose(images, 3,224,224), but if caused the error